# Basic RNN not converging to zero

Tags: backpropagation, recurrent-neural-network

I'm writing a basic RNN in Java using JBLAS.

My function for generating the hidden state is:

```
tanh(xU + sW)
```

Where **x** is the input vector and **s** is the previous hidden state vector. **U** and **W** are both the parameters that are being adjusted during backprop.

For modifying **U** and **W** I use:

```
U += dU * expectedValue * stepSize
W += dW * expectedValue * stepSize
```

Where **stepSize** is about 0.01, though I've tested lots of smaller values. The **expectedValue** is the same for both and it is just the value of the function I am trying to learn for testing.

For the cost function to determine how close my estimations are, I am using the mean squared error function:

```
1/n * (expectedValue^2 - predictedValue^2)
```

My cost function is not converging to zero over 10,000,000 iterations. Am I screwing up some of the math somewhere?

I am not using BPTT. I run the backprop every iteration over a single iteration.

Comment: Do you think this is a coding issue or an issue of your conceptual understanding of training NNs? (Note the former is off topic here, but the latter is on topic.) What language is that? Can you re-write it in pseudocode? I'm not sure you will be able to get an answer at present, even if this is on topic.

Comment: The problem is probably my understanding of NNs. I put the comments (starting with the //) that explain the math I am trying to use for each step. The code is only there for people who find that easier to read. If those aren't very clear, I can definitely try to add more info.